# Using a dynamic formula for greater than 0 for a range returns a Compile error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want a dynamic formula in cells (dynamic with respect to the cells location) through VBA as a part of a report I'm automating.
The general Excel formula is `=CountIfs($B:$B, $O6, D:D, ">0")`

So I tried
`Range("P6:U8").Formula = "=CountIfs($B:$B, $O6, D:D, ">0")"`

But it returns a

> Compile Error: End of statement.

The problem is with the greater than 0 part, `">0"` - when I substitute it with a normal number, everything's fine. But I want the cell to calculate values greater than 0.

How do I do it?

Comment: your range is across multiple columns "P6:U8", when you fill formula across columns your $O6 reference wont move, and your D:D reference will move.  is this intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think whats causing this is the quotation marks. Since you have a string within another string, you need to add more quotation marks

easy workaround is the following

```
strg = """>0"""
Range("A2:A3").Formula = "=CountIfs($G:$G, $B2, F:F, " & strg & ")"
```

Comment: "">0"" works. I feel so dumb to have not realised this earlier. Thanks a lot!